# Java read byte stream from browser different body lengths

Tags: javascript, java, html, post

I coded a small html webserver in java. I just implemented a fileupload feature, but i got an issue with it.

The browser sends the file via a XMLHttpRequest() and my webserver reads the bytestream of the file as described bellow.

```
    char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 8];

    int n;
    int total = 0;
    for(int count = 0; count < length; count++){
        System.out.println(count + "." + length);
        n = input.read( buffer );
        fileWriter.write( buffer, 0, n );
        count += n;

        total = count;
    }
    fileWriter.close();
```

the length is the size of the post-body -> so the for-loop knows when it's time to end. This method works perfectly - on windows. But not on linux! Indeed the bytestream is smaller than the body length, so my script waits for new bytes/packets until the post-body length is reached. For example, the last outputs are:

> 229404.280212
>   237597.280212
>   245790.280212
>   253983.280212
>   **262176**.280212

The number "262176" should be 280212. At this point, my servers waits for new packets...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Java is not javascript.....

Comment: @Dsafds but the request is sent with Javascript

Comment: @Dsafds the server side is coded in Java but the client side is coded in Javascript hence the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Have you tried capture the request in Wireshark in both Windows and Linux and compare them to see why the HTTP body of the post request is different?

Comment: The HTTP Body request isn't different. Is there another way to detect the end of stream?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to blindly believe that the file size *sent by the client* is actually accurate. You can't trust clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. Its bad to use a FileWriter.
But nevertheless, thanks to all who have tried to help me.

```
public void copy (InputStream in , File file, int length) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int cnt = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
    while(cnt < length)
    { 
        int n = in.read(buffer);
        fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
        cnt += n;
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues as well as some misunderstandings here.

Why are you incrementing `count` with the ++ operator? It should only be incremented by adding `n` to it each round of reads.
The `total` variable is just another name for count and you just use it to export it from the scope of the `for`? Why not just create `count` out of the loop?
Also the loop as it stands right now will never print the result of the last incrementation by `n`, since when `count` is incremented to - or above `length`, the loop terminates. Which means that the value that forced the loop to terminate will not be printed by the loop.
I would be suprised if this code does exactly what you intended to do.

I would replace your for loop with a while loop.

```
    char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 8];
    int total = 0;
    while (total < length){
        int n = input.read( buffer );
        fileWriter.write( buffer, 0, n );
        total += n;
        System.out.println(total + "." + length);
    }
    fileWriter.close();
```

You would also want to use your file writer in a try-with-resources construct and not use close() explicitly.

You should also make sure to add a timeout in the wile loop and also add a socket timeout, so you won't get stuck in an infinite loop nor an infinite block on the read.

Also note, that char is 2 bytes long in Java.

Comment: This is not the problem - your method does exactly the same like mine. The problem with the different length of the file still exist.